# MySQL Installer for Windows 64-bit

Tags: mysql

Is there a 64-bit installer for MySQL on Windows? When I go to the download pages for the community server I only see options for installers for 32-bit machines

[image]

Answer (score 5):

MySQL Installer is 32-bit but will install 64-bit binaries.

It's just  the installer that is in 32 bit

(thanks to David Lee) source : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92577